# Halting Clojure debugger after pressing the Continue Command

Tags: spacemacs, debugging, clojure, cider

I use Emacs with Cider to debug Clojure Code. After setting a breakpoint using the default debugging framework, there appears the list of debugging options one might execute shown in this Figure [image: Debug Options]

I experience recently a strange behaviour. If I press c(continue) while debugging a function and the debugger leaves the function debugged, it never stops in it again. This happens as well for the case when I press t(trace). It is as if the action is saved in the debugger. Every time this function is called, it executes the last command executed by the debugger. In this case continue or trace. I can see the trace result in the repl, thats why I came to this conclusion. However using the n(next) command does not lead to problems. Maybe its also saved and executed, but executing the next command never skips the function and always halts.

How to halt the function after pressing the continue command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which works but would be happy if a better solution was given.

The old behaviour of mine was after pressing c(continue), I had to close the repl and open it again and go to the method and mark it as debugged (which takes about 30sec).

The easier solution i found is calling

```
M-x cider-restart
```

and then going to the method marked as debugged, remove the dubug marking and then add it again (which takes all in all 5 seconds).

This way the method can still be debugged after pressing the continue command

A solution that disables this completely is still however highly appreciated.